# mysql finding regions based on coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of regions, all the regions are x,y to xy and a name

I want to be able to search and find based on a set of coordinates(x, y)  if it is within 10 meters of a region.

the range of the map these regions are on is from -6000,-6000 to 6000, 6000.

columns in the table are: Name, key, cox1, cox2, coy1, coy2.
from what I can tell the first coordinate is the lowest number.

they are always whole numbers, so no decimal points to worry about eg -3918, -4017, -3069, -2970.

there could be multiple regions that over lap, and in that case I would need to return all of those regions.

this will be passed from a webpage.

a few examples

- cox1, cox2, coy1, coy2
- -3918,-4017,-3069, -2970
- -3905, -3962, -2393, -2330
- -683, -683, -1459, -1459
- 4336, 4243, -4412, -432

ok, this seems to be what I want, but it is very hit and miss.
if i swap x1 and x2, or y1 and y2 around it will work in some combination but not always

```
    SELECT RegionNames.Name FROM RegionNames 
    WHERE ( -3500 between RegionNames.cox2 and RegionNames.cox1 )
    AND ( -3000 between RegionNames.coy1 and RegionNames.coy2 )
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also to make life easier always try to include 4/5 sample rows and which should match a given query which shouldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g. let's say you have region like this :

```
 Name          fromX     fromY     toX      toY  
 NorthEast      0          0       6000     6000
 NorthWest     -6000       0         -1     6000
```

etc.

And you have city like this :

```
 Name        X      Y
 MyCity    -2000   550
```

try :

```
 Select city.name, region.name from city
 join region on ((city.X between region.fromX and region.toX) 
 and (city.y between region.fromY and region.toY))
```

Comment: I did not think of between.  although the single set of coordinates aren't coming from another table.  thanks

Comment: If it works for your use, please consider accepting the answer ;). PS : the city table was just an example to see how to use the between idea ;).